# arch pacman insists on wrong kernel version

Tags: arch-linux, zfs, pacman

Output from `uname -a`

```
Linux janus 5.15.85-1-lts #1 SMP Thu, 22 Dec 2022 06:22:00 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

When I build zfs-liunx I get:

```
checking kernel source and build directories... done
checking kernel source directory... /usr/lib/modules/6.1.1-arch1-1/build
checking kernel build directory... /usr/lib/modules/6.1.1-arch1-1/build
```

I don't understand why it is checking module folders that are no longer on the system. But if they were (I moved the newer `/lib/modules/`) I get this when modprobing:

```
FATAL: Module zfs not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.85-1-lts
```

How do I tell pacman to ignore kernels that are no longer in use?

Comment: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/zfs-linux-lts

Comment: "no longer in use?", you have 5.15.85 now and it's asking for 6.1.1? Isn't that newer instead of "no longer on the system"?

Comment: No I want/need to use the lts version. The zfs-linux is what I'm attempting to use. It installs but copies to `/lib/modules/6.1.1` not 5.15.85.

Comment: Because the package is written to build for linux. It pulls in linux-headers (and, IIRC, linux, as a runtime dep) when you build it. For linux-lts, build/use zfs-linux-lts instead.